# How do I stop wordpress.com redirect to the primary

Tags: wordpress.com

I have a three domains on wordpress.com.  One of the domains is mapped and is the primary domain.  The other two were registered with Wordpress.com.  Whenever I type the two URLs that are not the primary in the address bar, they always redirect to the primary.  How do I get this to stop happening?  I would like the domains to take you to their own sites.